# create a correct XSL file for export data from filemaker

Tags: xml, xslt, filemaker

I have a database in Filemaker and I would like to export the table in xml format with this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ricette>
    <tipologia>Gelato al Latte</tipologia>
        <nome>Fior di Panna</nome>
            <ingrediente>BaseBiancaScirocco_2014 no condensato</ingrediente>
                <qta>1234</qta>
            <ingrediente>Panna Fresca 35%mg</ingrediente>
                <qta>1234</qta> 
            <ingrediente>Latte Intero Fresco AQ</ingrediente>
                <qta>1234</qta> 
    <tipologia>BaseGiallaScirocco</tipologia>
    ....
    ....
</ricette>
```

this is the data table in filemaker:

http://postimg.org/image/hjoparu8b/

I have created this XSL export file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fm="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="fm">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- expected columns -->
    <xsl:variable name="TYPO" select="1" />
    <xsl:variable name="NAME" select="2" />
    <xsl:variable name="INGREDIENT" select="3" />
    <xsl:variable name="QTY" select="4" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <ricette>
      <xsl:for-each select="fm:FMPXMLRESULT/fm:RESULTSET/fm:ROW">
          <tipologia><xsl:value-of select="fm:COL[$TYPO]/fm:DATA"/></tipologia>
          <nome><xsl:value-of select="fm:COL[$NAME]/fm:DATA"/></nome>
          <ingrediente><xsl:value-of select="fm:COL[$INGREDIENT]/fm:DATA"/></ingrediente>
          <qta><xsl:value-of select="fm:COL[$QTY]/fm:DATA"/></qta>
      </xsl:for-each> 
    </ricette>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ricette>

<tipologia>Gelato al Latte</tipologia>

<nome>Fior di Panna</nome>

<ingrediente>BaseBiancaScirocco_2014 no condensato</ingrediente>

<qta>1234</qta>

<tipologia>Gelato al Latte</tipologia>

<nome>Fior di Panna</nome>

<ingrediente>Panna Fresca 35%mg</ingrediente>

<qta>1234</qta>

<tipologia>Gelato al Latte</tipologia>

<nome>Fior di Panna</nome>

<ingrediente>Latte Intero Fresco AQ</ingrediente>

<qta>1234</qta>

...
...
<ricette>
```

In the result file there is a lot of space from row to row and ther isn't the tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. What difference does it make?
2. In order to have the result indented ***automatically***, start your
   stylesheet with:

   ```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
       xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
       xmlns:fm="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult" 
       xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"
       exclude-result-prefixes="fm xalan">
       <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" xalan:indent-amount="4"/>
   ```

   However, this will **not** produce the result you show, because your
   indenting is not based on the actual hierarchy of the output, where
   `tipologia`, `nome`, `ingrediente` and `qta` are all **siblings** of
   each other.

   In order to get fake indents as shown in your expected output, you
   would have to disable automatic indenting and insert the required
   white space as literal text, for example:

   ```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:fm="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult" 
   exclude-result-prefixes="fm">
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>

   <!-- expected columns -->
   <xsl:variable name="TYPO" select="1" />
   <xsl:variable name="NAME" select="2" />
   <xsl:variable name="INGREDIENT" select="3" />
   <xsl:variable name="QTY" select="4" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
       <ricette>
           <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
           <xsl:for-each select="fm:FMPXMLRESULT/fm:RESULTSET/fm:ROW">
               <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
               <tipologia><xsl:value-of select="fm:COL[$TYPO]/fm:DATA"/></tipologia>
               <xsl:text>&#10;&#9;&#9;</xsl:text>
               <nome><xsl:value-of select="fm:COL[$NAME]/fm:DATA"/></nome>
               <xsl:text>&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;</xsl:text>
               <ingrediente><xsl:value-of select="fm:COL[$INGREDIENT]/fm:DATA"/></ingrediente>
               <xsl:text>&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;</xsl:text>
               <qta><xsl:value-of select="fm:COL[$QTY]/fm:DATA"/></qta>
               <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
           </xsl:for-each> 
       </ricette>
   </xsl:template>
   ```
3. Note also that in your expected output, there seems to be grouping
   of ingredients by name - but your stylesheet does not do anything to
   achieve such grouping.
4. I am not sure what cause the double returns; I'd suggest you make
   sure your stylesheet uses only LF or CR as line delimiters, not
   both. It could also be an artifact created by the application you
   are using to view the result (esp. if you're on Windows).

Comment: yes, the indent is correct, the problem is that there are a lot of row empty (space from row to row) and i don't want this , I hope to be clear now, thanks!